# Agile Toolkit and Bootstrap

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap, atk4

I am using CI, but seriously considering a move to ATK4. The SaaS code I build always has to be desktop & mobile accessible, so recent projects have relied on Twitter's Bootstrap layouts to allow a good browser experience, regardless of screen size.

How does ATK4 handle mobile browsers, especially small screen like on phones? Is it really just a matter of the theme you choose with Theme Roller, and if so, are the any themes that are known for a both a good mobile & desktop experience with ATK4?

Comment: I guess it's just a matter of theme + JavaScript support. But Romans will probably answer you much better sometime soon. I'm still quite novice in ATK and also have very small experience with mobile apps.

Answer (score 1):

Agile Toolkit is targeted at the UI development, and primarily the desktop browser UI. The site is still usable on mobile devices, just like any jQuery UI site.

However, if you would like to use a different CSS engine, you are free to do so, simply change your `shared.html` file to have the necessary includes and you would need to write more templates. Well, you are writing templates right now anyway with CI, so it's pretty similar experience.